# JQuery $(document).ready(function () not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

This is the first page where I try to open the detail.html;

```
<a href="detail.html" data-role="none" role="link">
    <div class="place">name</div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="ammount">-&euro;4,<span class="fontsize14">25</span></div>
</a>
```

I have problems to load the scripts on detail.html (after href link is clicked on first page)

Here is my script in header of details.html(the page I go after href is clicked on first page), Problem is I can **NOT** get the console test print, that function is NOT called when details.html page is loaded. It only hits after I manually refresh the page

```
<script>
    $(document).bind("pageinit", function(){//or $(document).ready(function ()   
          console.log('test');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I read twice, but unable to understand your issue.

Comment: yep me too, there are some changes of a page with anchor but I really don't get what really the goal is. @Spring please clean it up, just tell us what is the concept, the goal and then what have you tried but really clear.

Comment: I added the `[jquery-mobile]` tag, since `pageinit` is a jQuery Mobile event. Just to confirm (since you didn't use the tag yourself), are you including the jQuery mobile library on your page?

Comment: @apsillers tnx, yes added, just a simple load function, and everybody says try this try that, isnt here a solid way of doing this?

Comment: Spring, you asked me to "look" at this. Jack's answer seems correct.

Comment: @andleer thanks for looking up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand your problem I think you need to first understand how jQuery Mobile "loads" external pages. By default when you click a link to a separate HTML page JQM loads the first *data-role="page"* on that page and attaches it to the DOM of the first page, the thing is JQM **only** loads that *page* div and not any scripts etc. that are outside that container.

If you want to run code for a second page, you either need to include that script on your first page and use event delegation (since the second page is not part of the DOM yet) or include the script withing the second page's *date-role="page"* wrapper.

Case in point in your case if you want to run code for your details page you either need to include the script on your first page for example assuming you have a div on your detail.html page like the following

```
<div id="details" data-role="page"> ..rest of your content 
</div>
```

Then on your first page you could do the following

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#details', function() {
  console.log('test');
});
```

Or alternatively you can include a script tag withing your "details" page wrapper.

EDIT:
As I mentioned this is the default behavior, however if you wish you can [tell jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html) to do a full post when loading a second page by adding in `data-ajax="false"` or `rel="external"` to your link for example

```
<a href="detail.html" data-ajax="false" data-role="none" role="link">
    <div class="place">name</div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="ammount">-&euro;4,<span class="fontsize14">25</span></div>
</a>
```

The difference between `data-rel="external"` and `data-ajax="false"` is if the second page is basically semantic in that `data-rel="external"` should be used if the second page is on a different domain.

Comment: tnx I just use href to change page I do not use $.mobile.changepage, so why Jquerry gets into the scene here?

Comment: That's the default behavior of jQuery Mobile, you can do a full page load by adding `data-rel="external"` or `data-ajax="false"` to your link.

Comment: Amazing it works, and it si that simple. but I havea little problem when try to go back  to previous page it triggers again, i only want it to trigger only loading the page not leaving the page

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, what triggers again? The `pageinit` event? Where is the script located?

Comment: I put the script on second page in <div id="details" data-role="page"> yes pageinit event

Comment: And its firing when you come back to the details page or when you come back to your first page? Because if you do a full post then every time you come to the page it will be reinitialized, in addition when you don't use the ajax model you lose page transitions. If you are designing your pages from scratch (as opposed to retrofitting existing pages to use JQM) then unless you have reason not to you will probably want to go with the default ajax model.

Comment: tnx if I use data-ajax="false then can I still pass paremeters and jStore objects bwteeen pages?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22923/discussion-between-jack-and-spring)

Comment: could you also look at this one tnx! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609080/jquery-mobile-how-to-detect-refresh

Answer (score 1):

I made you an working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Eqzd2/

```
$("#second").live('pagebeforeshow', function () {
    console.log('This will only execute on second page!');
});
```

You can use on instead of live if you are using last version of jQuery.

Also take a look at my article about event flow in jQM page transition: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14010308/1848600

Comment: I use 1.2 version. should I put this script on first OR second page?

Comment: and '#second' is u mean like '#details.html'

Comment: Yes, take a look at my working example. If you have few html files this code should be in first one if jQM is using ajax loading or any every page if you are not using ajax page loading.

Comment: tnx I have multiples files but couldnt make it work, in my case should i write "#details.html" ? as you can see how I call the other page from href

Comment: I would be glad if you edit the jsfiddle code to work with 2 html pages, I couldnt make it work in my case

Comment: Cant make it with jsFiddle but give me your email and I will send you an example with two files.

Comment: thank you very much for your example, while it is very helpful, jacks solution fit better to my situation